# '/sync_depth' and '/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized

Tags: rviz, timesynchronizer, laser-scan, depthimage-to-laserscan

Im using depthimage_to_laserscan package to get the laserscan message.Things i have tried

1)sync the time stamp of both the topics using    ApproximateTimeSynchronizer with slop value of 0.0001 .

2)Made sure that both topics are published under same frame.

yet i'm unable to get these topics to sync and i suspect because of this issue i cant see laserscan message in rviz.

Thanks in advance

[image: this is what my terminal window reads]

time stamp of both the topics
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that both topics have messages with correct timestamps published? 
You can ensure that the timestamps published are correct by echoing the topics with 
`ros2 topic echo /sync_depth`

Comment: yes !!, please have a look at my post- i have edited it .There you can see upto 14 digits  in timestamps of both the topics are same